# Simplicial cup product on torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm trying to compute the simplicial cup product on the torus (using $\Delta$-complexes) but running into a problem: each way I draw the fundamental polygon I get different answers!  When I draw it as Hatcher does in 2.1, and label the vertices as on the left below,

[image]

([original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iROzV.png))

I get the correct answer, but I get the wrong answer when I use the triangulation on the right (or any other ones I tried).  Why is this happening?  What's special about Hatcher's triangulation?

**Edit**: Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ generate $H^1(X; \mathbf{Z})$, dual to $a$ and $b$, respectively, and let $\varphi$, $\psi$ be representative cochains. Then using the triangulation on the right, I get $$\alpha \smallsmile\alpha(A) = \varphi(A|[01])\varphi(A|[13]) = \varphi(a)\varphi(c) = 1$$ where $A$ is the upper 2-simplex, and this is already wrong.

Comment: Can you show your calculations?

Comment: It's impossible to say anything unless you show your work. Both triangulations should yield the same answer.

Comment: I've added them (let me know if more details are required)

Comment: wow, nice diagram.

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help :)

Comment: I think that you have a typo: $\alpha, \beta \in H^1(X; \mathbb{Z})$ (you have them in degree $2$).

Comment: @SammyBlack you are right, thank you.

Comment: Notice that your pictures are not triangulations... IIRC one needs at least 14 triangles.

Comment: I think that he's using Hatcher's $\Delta$-complex notion, that lets you get away with fewer triangles at the expense of a vertex set not uniquely identifying a simplex.

Comment: You have to explain more of your notation.  What is $A$?  In particular, how is it oriented?  Why do the four corners of the square carry distinct labels when they are in fact all identified to one point?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez yes, I'm using $\Delta$-complexes, sorry for not specifying.

Comment: @SammyBlack $A$ is the upper 2-simplex [0,1,3] oriented as indicated in the diagram.  Yes, all the vertices are identified to a point, but I have to label them somehow for computation anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are performing an operation which is "not allowed": The cup product $\alpha\smile\alpha$ is a **cohomology class** in $H^2(X;\mathbb Z)$. Now such a class is determined only up to coboundaries: If $φ$ and $\psi$ represent the same class, then $φ-\psi$ is a coboundary, and that means it vanishes on cycles. So if $C$ is a cycle in $C_2(X)$, then $φ(C)=\psi(C)$. We cannot expect $φ$ and $\psi$ to agree on ordinary simplices, like the upper triangle $A$ in the right-hand diagram. So we should not apply a cohomology class to an ordinary chain, but only to cycles, or to homology classes.
On the cycle $A-B$, $α⌣α$ gives $0$, since $α(A)=α(B)=-1$ (I'm taking $-1$ instead of $1$ since in my calculation the cocycle $φ$ representing $\alpha$ maps $a$ to $1$, $c$ to $-1$, and $b$ to $0$, and I think a $φ$ which sends $c$ to $1$ only works if $c$ points in the opposite direction).

Comment: So say we're trying to compute cup product in integral cohomology using a $\Delta$-complex structure on the Klein bottle where there are no 2-cycles to pair with, rather than the torus. Is this hopeless? Am I forced to subdivide to create a simplicial structure that I can globally order?